# When message queue is created?

Tags: winapi

Consider the following code:

```
unsigned int __stdcall func( LPVOID ) {
    LRESULT result = ::PostThreadMessage( ::GetCurrentThreadId(), 0, 0, 0 );
    return 0;
}

int wmain() {
    _beginthreadex( NULL, 0, func, NULL, 0, NULL );
    ...
}
```

Why does ::PostThreadMessage succeed? I think that it should fail because a message queue should not be created by that moment

Comment: Did you check that `PostThreadMessage()` actually succeeds (i.e. does not return `0` and set the last error to `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID`)?

Comment: Yep, PostThreadMessage returns 1. GetLastError() returns 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calling `PostThreadMessage()` on the current thread, the system is able to create the message queue on demand.  If you were calling `PostThreadMessage()` and passing the ID of a thread other than the calling thread, then it would fail if that thread did not have a message queue.

For example, consider the following variant of your code:

```
unsigned int __stdcall func( LPVOID ) {
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned int threadID;
    _beginthreadex( NULL, 0, func, NULL, 0, &threadID );
    LRESULT result = ::PostThreadMessage( threadID, 0, 0, 0 );
    DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
    return 0;
}
```

Because we are now attempting to post the message from the main thread, to the worker thread, `result` comes back as 0 (i.e. an error), and `error` is set to `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID` as described by the [documentation for `PostThreadMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28VS.85%29.aspx).

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. GetLastError returns `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID` if `idThread` is not a valid thread identifier, or if the thread specified by `idThread` does not have a message queue.